# How to use Enum to get the number of records based on the selected type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using Linq-To-Entities and I am trying to use Enum for retrieving the number (count) of items based on the status. For instance, the status of item could be active or inactive or pending. What I did in my Business Logic Layer is the following:

```
public enum ItemStatus   
    {
        Active = 1,
        Inactive = 2,
        Pending = 3
    }

public int getActiveItemsCount()
    {
        using (ItemsDBEntities context = new ItemsDBEntities())
        {
            return context.Items.Count();
        }
    }
```

Here's is my database schema:

```
Items Table: ID, Name, StatusID
Status Table: ID, Status
```

As you see, there is a relationship between Items and Status tables.

What I want is to modify the second method in such a way that will the number of items based on the status of the item. **Could you please tell me how to create a method similar to the second one for getting the number of items based on the status listed by Enum?**

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the StatusID matches your Enum, then like this on EF 4 (which has no native Enum support):

```
public int getActiveItemsCount(ItemStatus status)
{
    using (ItemsDBEntities context = new ItemsDBEntities())
    {
        var enumvalue=(int)status;
        return context.Items.Where(item => item.StatusID == enumvalue).Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I guess StatusID is just an ID for table Status (in which Status is ItemStatus enum) but anyway concept is pretty clear!

Comment: @Adriano yes enums storing as integer in database

Comment: @Selman22 yes, I mean: maybe StatusID is not an enum. It's ID of an item (of type Status). That item has a property Status, that property is our enum (to cast to int and compare).

Comment: @Adriano yes,in this case you right. but OP can do it with storing the status variable directly in items table.he don't need to another table for this.when creating a new record enum value automatically converting integer,and when getting status all we need to do is cast it to ItemStatus enum type

Comment: @James World, thank you for your help. As I am a new user of Linq, could you please tell me how I can use this method in my UI? I tried to use it as the following:`Label8.Text = item.getActiveItemsCount(1);` but I got a red line under the name of the method.

Comment: As written, you should pass the status you are looking for. Eg. `item.getActiveItemsCount(ItemStatus.Active)`. Given the usage, maybe `int GetCountOfItemsWithStatus(ItemStatus status)` is a better signature, or just hard code the status...

Comment: @JamesWorld, the problem is that I have all the code mentioned in my question above in my Business Logic Layer. And now in the UI, I am saying `Label8.Text = item.getActiveItemsCount(ItemStatus.Active);` and it gave me a red line under `ItemStatus` saying that: **The name ItemStatus does not exist in the current context**. Why???!!!